# Problems with immidiate concistency in terraform AWS lambda layer

Tags: python, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm having trouble configuring my tf insrastructure of AWS Lambda + Lambda Layer. I'll start with what I want to achieve: I want to implement a Lambda that uses a Layer for dependencies (in my case - using python - installed from `requirements.txt`), and I want the layer to be built and uploaded **if and only if** there was a change to the `requirements.txt` file. 
I managed to get there using the following terraform:

```
# Layer

resource "null_resource" "layer_code" {
  triggers = {
    requirements_file = md5(file("${local.project_root}/requirements.txt")) 
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
image_name="public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.9"
export_folder="tf/.deployment/layer-dependencies/python"
update_pip_cmd="pip install --upgrade pip"
install_dependencies_cmd="pip install -r requirements.txt -t $export_folder"
docker_cmd="$update_pip_cmd; $install_dependencies_cmd; exit"

echo "Will build layer in '$export_folder'"
docker run -v "${local.project_root}":/var/task "$image_name" /bin/sh -c "$docker_cmd"
EOF
  }
}

data "archive_file" "layer_code_archive" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${local.project_root}/tf/.deployment/layer-dependencies"
  output_path = "layer.zip"
  depends_on  = [
    null_resource.layer_code
  ]
}

resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "dependencies_layer" {
  filename         = data.archive_file.layer_code_archive.output_path
  layer_name       = "${local.service_name}-layer"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.layer_code_archive.output_path)
  skip_destroy     = true
}

# Lambda

data "archive_file" "service_code_archive" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${local.project_root}/src"
  output_path = "service.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "service_lambda" {
  function_name                  = "${local.service_name}-lambda"
  role                           = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec_role.arn
  handler                        = "lambda_handler.handle"
  runtime                        = "python3.9"
  filename                       = data.archive_file.service_code_archive.output_path
  source_code_hash               = filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.service_code_archive.output_path)
  layers                         = [
    aws_lambda_layer_version.dependencies_layer.arn
  ]
}
```

This almost does the trick, but it's not good enough, as it requires **two runs** of `tf apply`:

1. Assume we are in a stable state (`tf plan` is empty), now I change `requirements.txt`.
2. Running `tf plan` outputs `Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.`

   - `null_resource.layer_code must be replaced` (because `requirements.txt` has changed).
   - `data.archive_file.layer_code_archive will be read during apply`.
3. Running `tf apply` outputs `Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 1 destroyed.` (layer was built locally, nothing actually changed in AWS).
4. Running `tf plan` **again** outputs: `Plan: 1 to add, 1 to change, 1 to destroy.`

   - `aws_lambda_layer_version.dependencies_layer must be replaced` (because `source_code_hash` changed, due to previous `tf apply`).
   - `aws_lambda_function.service_lambda will be updated in-place` (because layer will change).
5. Running `tf apply` **again** updates the layer + lambda.
6. We are back in stable state (`tf plan` is empty).

The point is that while this is eventual consistent, its **not** immediate consistent (what I want it to be). 
I tried setting `dependencies_layer.source_code_hash` with `md5(requirements.txt)` , and this does give immidiate concistency, but the problem is that after 1 deployment, the `dependencies_layer.source_code_hash` is saved in tf state using the actual layer code, which causes `tf plan` to always be out of sync (even though it will reach the exact same code state). 
So, the question is: is there some option to explicitly trigger `dependencies_layer` update when `layer_code` is changed? That would solve the issue. If not, maybe there is some other type of best practice solution for this situation (lambda layer that depeneds on requirements file)? It does not sound rare (and still I wasn't able to find anything useful). Also, is running 2 (or more) cycles of `tf plan` + `tf apply` considered bad practice? Sounds to me like it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem by workaround, I don't use docker for building layer package and I don't use terraform `data.archive_file`, I create zip for layer in the `null_resource.pip_install` after installing all requirements libraries.

The main workaround in my idea, it was triggered recreation lambda layer, since aws_lambda_layer_version doesn't have triggers attribute, I was able to make it with add `filemd5(requirements.txt)` to `filename` attribute of lambda layer (`${local.service_name}-${filemd5("${local.lambda_code_path}/requirements.txt")}-layer.zip"`)

so then requirements will be change it will triggered to recreate `null_resource.pip_install` and `aws_lambda_layer_version.layer`

```
resource "null_resource" "pip_install" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      pip3 install --target $TMP_PATH/${local.service_name}-$MD5_REQUIREMENTS-layer/python -r ${local.lambda_code_path}/requirements.txt
      cd $TMP_PATH/${local.service_name}-$MD5_REQUIREMENTS-layer
      zip -r ./../${local.service_name}-$MD5_REQUIREMENTS-layer.zip python
    EOT
    environment = {
      TMP_PATH         = local.tmp_folder_path
      MD5_REQUIREMENTS = filemd5("${local.lambda_code_path}/requirements.txt")

    }
    working_dir = path.root
  }

  triggers = {
    dependencies_versions = filemd5("${local.lambda_code_path}/requirements.txt")
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "layer" {

  filename            = "${local.tmp_folder_path}/${local.service_name}-${filemd5("${local.lambda_code_path}/requirements.txt")}-layer.zip"
  layer_name          = "${local.service_name}-layer"

  depends_on = [
    null_resource.pip_install
  ]
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, I will try it soon.
You mean, the main difference between the solutions, is to add the MD5 to the file name, so the layer will force change on file change?
It means there is no layer zip file when running `tf plan`, isnt this a problem?

Comment: _is to add the MD5 to the file name, so the layer will force change on file change?_  - yes

_It means there is no layer zip file when running tf plan, isnt this a problem?_ - It will be problem only if you use `data.archive_file` because data always try to find required folder for generation a new zip, but I think it is doesn't suitable for AWS lambda layer, since terraform code can be used by several persons and it means that they always should have folder with generated dependency (or it should be  stored in repository) that I think not so good